# how to remove fetched record field in php using j query

Tags: php, jquery, fetch

how to remove field using jQuery?

I have to fetch record from a table using for each loop `php-codeigniter`

and my view looks like shown below attached pic.
[image]

when I click to remove button then remove corresponding input row field? how do we use jQuery?

currently i have click on remove button than remove all inputs fiels,

```
$(document).on('click', '.RemoveBtn', function() {
    $(this).closest('div').remove();
});
```

and this is my view

```
<div class="col-md-7">
<?php
if (!empty($marks)) {
foreach ($marks as $key => $value) {
?>
<input name="mytext1[]" placeholder="Marks1" required="" value="<?php echo $value->marks1 ?>"
class="right" type="number"/>
<input name="mytext2[]" placeholder="Marks2" required="" value="<?php echo $value->marks2 ?>"
class="right" type="number"/>
<input name="mytext3[]" placeholder="Marks3" required="" value="<?php echo $value->marks3 ?>"
class="right" type="number"/>
<span class="text-left"></span>
<input type="button" value="Remove" class='RemoveBtn'/>
<?php
}
}
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap it in a single div.

```
<div class="col-md-7">
<?php
if (!empty($marks)) {
foreach ($marks as $key => $value) {
?>
<div class="mainDiv">
<input name="mytext1[]" placeholder="Marks1" required="" value="<?php echo $value->marks1 ?>"
class="right" type="number"/>
<input name="mytext2[]" placeholder="Marks2" required="" value="<?php echo $value->marks2 ?>"
class="right" type="number"/>
<input name="mytext3[]" placeholder="Marks3" required="" value="<?php echo $value->marks3 ?>"
class="right" type="number"/>
<span class="text-left"></span>
<input type="button" value="Remove" class='RemoveBtn'/>
</div>
<?php
}
}
?>
</div>
```

### JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click', '.RemoveBtn', function() {
    $(this).parent('.mainDiv').remove();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

what has to be done is, need to hit a ajax call from that button. like :

```
 $('.button').on('click',function(){
   $.get('your url',{id:$(this).data('id')});
 })
```

Keep primary id with each button. (make login accordingly).
Apply php logic their, and have it accordingly. kindly be aware of security issues, its highly insecure to do so.